# Layout with text and images where bottom and top is aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Trying to create layout like this:

[image]

Rules:

- 2 columns.
- Each column can contain any number of images (2 and 3 in our case).
- Each image can have a caption with any length.
- The first images in each column must be aligned.
- The last images in each column must be aligned.
- We do not know how much lines caption will occupy, but we know aspect ratio of each image.

Current work in progress on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LpL2jmgj/
Will post updates if I'll find a solution.

I guess it's not possible to do this just via CSS even with `display:grid`?

Comment: Is col-1 / col-2 width ratio fixed?

Comment: @fen1x No. Each column can have any width, but images in them must form a rectangle - so top part of the first image in each column is aligned vertically and bottom part of the last image in each column is aligned vertically.

Comment: With the given image, if there were to be 3 lines of text under the top left image, where should that _white space_ be in the 2nd column?

Comment: @LGSon https://imgur.com/a/uBddL

Comment: @Marvin3 With that image you also added text beneath the top right image ... we did that text came from?

Comment: @LGSon sorry, took screeshot from different modified demo, here is with the same amount of text https://imgur.com/a/N23tu

Comment: So when text increase the image decrease, which was what happened in that last screenshot, so if I then say, _that the images adjust to the space left consumed by the text_, would that be correct?

Comment: @LGSon the width of container is always 100%, it is responsive. The height 
 might vary depending on aspect ratios of images and height of captions. Ideally two columns should have the same width, but it is possible only when images and captions have the same size in both columns. So width of each column should adjust a little bit to make height equal.

Comment: Have all the images same aspect ratio?

Comment: @LGSon no, any image can have any aspect ratio and there can be any number of images.

Comment: After some thoughts, you will need script here, ... CSS Grid might, but I don't think so.

Comment: @LGSon yea, I guess so, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

is this your answer???
i just use flex box and a little of margin , i hope you like it :)

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin : 5px;
}
.rows{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin : 5px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
p{
  margin : 2px;
}
.col {
  width: 100px;
  margin : 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.col1 {
  margin : 5px;
  flex : 5;
  background-color : red;
  height : 200vh;
}
.col2{
  margin : 5px;
  flex:3;
  background-color : blue;
  height : 200vh;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rows">
  <div class="col1">
     <div class="columns">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
    <img style="width:100%;" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <div class="rows">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
      <p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
   <div class="columns">
      <img style="width:100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <div class="rows"><p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> </div>
      <div class="rows"><p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> </div>
      <div class="rows"><p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <img style="width:100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
      <img style="width:100%" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed _"The last images in each column must be aligned at their bottom."_

Comment: It was me who downvoted...and if you fix it, I will retract my down vote, and maybe even upvote :) ... but until then your answer doesn't work, hence downvoted

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter if it has a little diff, images is not bottom aligned, which they should...and if you add more text under an image, it will change again, so this answer does not solve the question.

Comment: And no one is impolite here, just telling you what is wrong.

Comment: you can say what's wrong here in comment not with giving minus points!!

Comment: Instead of argue with me, and tell me what I should do, update your answer with something that work and problem solved...or delete it and you get the minus point back, or you plan to keep a wrong answer?